# Merge datetime series to multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a multi-index data frame:

```
tuples = list(zip(*[
    ['8000', '8000', '8000', '8100', '8100', '8200'],
    ['2021-04-02', '2021-04-05', '2021-04-06', '2021-04-02', '2021-04-10', '2021-04-28']
]))

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['cardNumber', 'date_only'])

values = [4, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=values, index=idx, columns=['Count'])

df.index = df.index.set_levels([df.index.levels[0], pd.to_datetime(df.index.levels[1])])
```

I also have a series with the days in April:

```
april_days = pd.date_range(start='2021-04-01', end='2021-04-30').to_series(index=None, name='Date')
```

In `df`, not every day appears so I want to merge `april_days` with `df` so there would be an empty value if there was no observation.

I've tried `merge` with no luck and  `concat` where `axis=1` but that did not work either. How can I combine these two data sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to create a new index based on the existing and reindex the dataframe. Note, for this solution I do not create a series object for april_days:

```
april_days = pd.date_range(start='2021-04-01', end='2021-04-30')
```

For creating the new index, I repeat the cardNumber index for each date in april_dates:

```
idx_1 = df.index.levels[0].repeat(len(april_days))
```

Afterwards, I create a new time index. Therefore, I repeat the april_days 3 times, since there are three cardNumbers. Note, here you need an other method for repeating since else the april_dates would have the following order `[01.04, 01.04, 01.04, 02.04,...]`. However we need `[01.04, 02.04, ..., 30.04, 01.04,...]`. Therefore, I use the following method:

```
 import numpy as np
 idx_time = np.array([april_days.values] * 3).flatten()
```

Now I can create the new multiindex:

```
idx = list(zip(idx_1, idx_time))
```

And reindex the existing dataframe:

```
df.reindex(idx)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much. I used the following code to make the time index dynamic.    

`num_unique_cardNumber = len(df.index.levels[0])`  
    
`idx_time = np.array([april_days.values] * num_unique_cardNumber).flatten()`